# SnapSVG browser incompatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

How come this code works smoothly in chrome and not in firefox?
I use `SnapSVG`.

JS:

```
var pinguin = Snap("#pinguin");

Snap.load("pinguin.svg", bodyload ) ;
function bodyload( data ){     
    pinguin.append( data );
};
```

Html:

```
<svg id="pinguin" ></svg>
<script src="snap.svg.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

What I get on Chrome:
[image: Chrome]
What I get on Firefox:
[image]

I tried to make a fiddle, but the [fiddle doesn't work.](http://jsfiddle.net/7gcv6w18/)

Instead, the code and display can be get here: http://www.pinguin.moe/

Do you know how can I fix the display on Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a width and height to your outer SVG. There is one in the svg file, but not in the markup on the main page. If you set this to 800,600 for example, it should work.

```
<svg id="pinguin" preserveaspectratio="xMinYMin meet" viewbox="0 0 300 750" width="800" height="600">
```

Comment: Thanks, but then the SVG doesn't take the full screen in a responsive way, like what I get on Chrome. I mean, right now on Chrome, the SVG takes the full screen height even if the User resize the windows, thanks to the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute. But when removing the width and height, it doesn't keep that ratio :(